# NumPy index tricks causing lag

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, iteration

Code is calculating render positions for isometric blocks

```
def blockrender(blockcoords):
    cubex = gridxcorner + blockcoords[2] * xshiftconst - blockcoords[1] * xshiftconst
    cubey = gridycorner + blockcoords[2] * yshiftconst + blockcoords[1] * yshiftconst - blockcoords[0] * blockheightconstant

    display.blit(grass_img, (cubex, cubey))

for blockcoords, blocktype in numpy.ndenumerate(chunk_datanp):
    blockrender(blockcoords)
```

cProfile says index_tricks is lagging it out but isn't this what NumPy is supposedly efficient at with huge array sizes? Or is my base Python/logic just bad?

Comment: Your understanding is bad. Numpy is fast when doing multiple operations at once, using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming). Here you are using numpy array as a list and using slow vanilla Python to do the calculations

Comment: Even though you use `numpy.ndenumerate`, you are still iterating at python `for` speeds.

Comment: Yea I figured that out by googling for last hour, just got confused cause numpy documentation tells you to do it this way. I am trying to figure out the best way to iterate using vectorization rn.

Comment: The simple answer is, don't iterate.  But sometimes you must, and accept the time cost.

Comment: So my thinking is that I use vectorized to transform my array into an array of render positions, but then I still can't avoid iterating over that array to blit each block in pygame and that that is a limit of pygame's rendering maybe (after all pygame is not designed to be fast lol). So maybe I have to get into OpenGL hell or something where I can give it some vaugely vectorized / non-iterative render call.